# Web Scraping in flashcore.com

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to scrape from Flashcore.

When I try to run it, I get a **list index out of range**.

Is it possible to add a zero when `set1` doesn't exist?

Can anyone help me??

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 


url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/table-tennis/others-men/tt-star-series/results/'

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
async def get_scores():
    r = await asession.get(url)
    await r.html.arender()
    return r

results = asession.run(get_scores)
results = results[0]


times = results.html.find("div.event__time")
home_players = results.html.find("div.event__participant.event__participant--home") 
scores_home = results.html.find('div > div.event__score.event__score--home')
scores_home_set1 = results.html.find('div > div.event__part.event__part--home.event__part--1')


dict_res = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(times)):
        dict_res['times'].append(times[i].text)
        dict_res['home_players'].append(home_players[i].text)
        dict_res['scores_home'].append(scores_home[i].text)
        dict_res['set1'].append(scores_home_set1[i].text)
        
df_res = pd.DataFrame(dict_res)
df_res.to_csv('ttstar.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer in this post. This is a different way to get the same. Thank you so much @AlbertoCastillo.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/table-tennis/others-men/tt-star-series/results/'
driver.get(url)

data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match')
data_clean = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    data_clean.append(data[i].text)

data_clean = [x.replace("\n", "|") for x in data_clean]
data_clean
```

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/394992/191389